# Re-locking bootloader with stock ROM/recovery - Wileyfox Swift 2 Plus

Tags: twrp, fastboot, bootloader, 8.1-oreo, bootloader-lock

I recently unlocked the bootloader on my Wileyfox Swift 2 Plus to take a partition image, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287932).  I didn't flash the recovery or make any change to the ROM, and the device is not rooted.  After a factory reset (to Android 8.1.0, if that helps), I now need to re-lock the bootloader, but `fastboot oem lock` renders it unable to boot normally.  I can still boot into fastboot mode or recovery, but the phone won't start normally until I run `fastboot oem unlock` again.  How can I get this back to factory settings, with the bootloader locked?

Note that I'm not interested in reasons to keep the bootloader unlocked.  Having the bootloader locked is a requirement for several apps that I need to use, and I'm not going to try to bypass that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reflash the stock rom, or if your only problem that apps wouldn't work install magisk and by this apps you can use magisk hide.

Comment: Why would reflashing the ROM help?

Comment: Maybe unlocking has broke any function on your software. [this i*ve found on Xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/swift-2/help/relock-bootloader-return-to-stock-t3758646) @fminl